# Unable to connect to Openfire server (using smack api)

Tags: java, android, tcp, xmpp

I am trying to run this code using smack 4.1.0

```
 Thread D= new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SmackConfiguration.setDefaultPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
                XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .setUsernameAndPassword("harsh", "pass")
                        .setServiceName("192.168.0.200")
                        .setHost("192.168.0.200")
                        .setPort(5223).setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible)
                        .build();

                AbstractXMPPConnection conn2 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
                try {
                    conn2.connect();

                    conn2.login();

                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
                    presence.setStatus("Gone fishing");
                    // Send the packet (assume we have an XMPPConnection instance called "con").
                    conn2.sendStanza(presence);

                } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("TAG", e.toString());
                }

                ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(conn2);


                Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("harsh@192.168.0.200");

                try {
                    newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
                }
                catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });





        D.start();


    }
```

This gives me an error :

```
05-15 14:59:35.350    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 10000ms (~10s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'. 05-15 14:59:35.351    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:192) 05-15 14:59:35.352    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:114) 05-15 14:59:35.352    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWaitOrThrow(SynchronizationPoint.java:97) 05-15 14:59:35.352    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:837) 05-15 14:59:35.352    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:360) 05-15 14:59:35.354    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at com.example.smacktester.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:50) 05-15 14:59:35.354    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 05-15 14:59:35.355    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester D/TAG﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 10000ms (~10s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'. 05-15 14:59:35.365    4417-4444/com.example.smacktester W/AbstractXMPPConnection﹕ Connection closed with error
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ��P@1:8 in java.io.BufferedReader@16ea33d4)
            at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:432)
            at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1151)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfDoneAndResumptionNotPossible(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1226) 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfAppropriate(XMPPTCPConnection.java:336) 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.sendStanza(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:609) 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatManager.sendMessage(ChatManager.java:365) 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat.sendMessage(Chat.java:114) 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat.sendMessage(Chat.java:98) 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at com.example.smacktester.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:71) 05-15 14:59:35.377    4417-4439/com.example.smacktester W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 05-15 14:59:56.335    4417-4417/com.example.smacktester I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2763795b time:38739229 05-15 15:00:19.772   4417-4427/com.example.smacktester W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took:
10.531ms 05-15 15:02:44.503    4417-4427/com.example.smacktester W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.832ms
```

**And, after enabling debugging in the local openfire server, I get this message:**

```
2015.05.15 14:50:03 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com]
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819441/certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-wit/26360672#26360672

Comment: can you provide a solution that does not require the use of an external library ?

Comment: solution that does not require require the use of an external library ,means you don't want to use smack?correct me if i am wrong!!!!

Comment: no, i dont want to use MemorizingTrustManager

Comment: then just disable SecurityMode in your XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration 

`.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)`

Comment: I just did that. The problem persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77887/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-dev).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS per discussion with user problem was `.setPort(5223)` in XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration .Port 5223 by default Client SSL Port in Openfire,

```
you can change this port setting in  Openfire 3.10 from Admin panel
```

> Server >> Server Settings >> Client Connections

error

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response
> received within reply timeout. Timeout was 10000ms (~10s).

Means You are trying to connecting SSL enabled port [5223] with out doing SASL negotiation.
Means you need to Store SSL certificate provided by XMPP server[Opnefire] in your application[some where in your internal/external memory] ,and use same certificate for further communication with Xmpp server on SSL Port.

> For SSL authentication you can user [Truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819441/certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-wit/26360672#26360672)
>
> For more information on XMPP SASL negotiation refer this [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920#page-19)

Comment: I am facing similar issue, can you tell what is the solution for the same